# Filter out empty address in web3.js

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

How to detect empty address that has initial value of `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` in web3.js?

What I'm doing now is:

```
if (address !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
   ...
}
```

Is there any simpler way to filter out empty addresses or a helper method in web3 that can create this value(like `address(0)` in Solidity)? It's quite bothering to count(or type) exact number of all that `0`s.

Comment: Maybe `web3.toBigNumber(address).isZero()`?

Comment: @smarx Really nice to know that web3 depends on BigNumber library. Why couldn't I think this way.. brilliant.

Comment: You could post it as an answer and I can mark it accepted. Seems like your suggestion is the best I can think of so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from @smarx's way: `web3.toBigNumber(address).isZero()`

You can use a simple regex, which is shorter:

```javascript
const emptyAddress = /^0x0+$/.test(address);
```

Comment: Nice one! I think `/^0x0{40}$/` may be clearer since an address in ethereum is 20 bytes 

Comment: Yeah I know, but if you use: `web3.toHex(0)` it will only give you `0x0`, who knows, if ethereum increase the address length, this code will still work ;)

Comment: Good catch. That would be a case where you generate an empty address in web3 side. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use OpenZeppelin's Test Helpers.

They have a constant called `ZERO_ADDRESS` which equals to zero address you mentioned.

[More Info Here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#zero_address)

**Usage**

First, you need to install:

```sh
npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers
```

In JS file:

```js
const constants = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

console.log(constants.ZERO_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const {constants} = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');`?